# Oracle stored procedures ... any problems putting an OUT parameter before an IN parameter?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Should the ordering of parameter types matter when calling a stored procedure in oracle?

For example (please forgive syntax errors)

```
my_proc (
param_a IN NUMBER
, param_b IN STRING
, param_c OUT NUMBER
, param_d OUT STRING
) begin
param_c = param_a
param_d = param_b
end
```

When we do something like the above we get the values passed in back out in the OUT parameters (again please forgive the specific syntax).

However, when we move param_c over param_b we get 0.0 and NULL instead of the values passed in.

```
my_proc (
param_a IN NUMBER
, param_c OUT NUMBER
, param_b IN STRING
, param_d OUT STRING
) begin
param_c = param_a
param_d = param_b
end
```

We are testing this in PL/SQL.

Is there something we're overlooking?

Thanks
BayouBob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who considered this, but it turns out to be something kinda simple.  It appears the way you call a stored procedure through ojdbc6 makes a big difference.

I should confess this was originally a java / oracle question we were trying to confirm with PL/SQL.

If we called the stored procedure as 'call my_proc(...)' the ordering of IN and OUT parameters appears to be important; whereas, 'begin my_proc(...) end' works just fine.

Note: this applies to building a callablestatement in Java 6 with ojdbc6.

Comment: Are you using named or positional parameters? Named sometimes aren't handled as you might expect and are treated as positional, which might explain what you saw.

Comment: We are switching from positional to named in an attempt to decouple ourselves from the whims of the client who provides the database we must connect to.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your IN/OUT parameters in whatever order you want. How are you calling this procedure? If you pass in an empty string you will get a NULL output value. For example:

```
declare
   param_c   NUMBER;
   param_d   VARCHAR2(100);
begin

  my_proc (
    0,
    param_c,
    '',
    param_d
  );

  dbms_output.put_line(param_c);

  dbms_output.put_line(nvl(param_d, 'null'));

end;
```

This should output:

```
0
null
```